# Robotics Project based on slam algorithm

Tags: robotics, slam-algorithm

I am very beginner in robotics. I want to make a robotics project based on slam algorithms. I know many algorithm and i have the confidence to implement it in any language but i dont have any idea based on image processing and hardware. So, can anyone give a tuotorial based on slam based robotics projects[including how hardware organized and how image processing is done for that project], after seeing that i can make a slam based robotics project from my own.

In addition, If anyone give me a video lecture series for that then it would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to do something similar last year. I created two systems. The first system made use of a camera and laser to detect objects and determine their location relative to the system itself. The second system was a little robot with tracks (wheels would be better), that used dead reckoning to keep track of its own location relative to its starting location. The techniques worked really well, but unfortunately I did not have the time to combine the two systems. I can however provide you with some documentation that was incredibly useful for me at that time.

These tutorials provide information on both the hardware and the software.

Optical Triangulation (detection of objects with a camera and laser) :

http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/200110/vision.htm

Dead Reckoning (a technique to keep track of one's own location) :

http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/200010/dead_reckoning_article.html